# Moving Files by name

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a vbs that would determine the following:

1. is the file a *.dbf?
2. is the file name numeric?

A yes to both questions would allow the script to move said file into another folder. Here's what I have so far:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "D:\Folder"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set DirFiles = objFolder.Files
Dim oFile
For Each objFile in DirFiles
    If "dbf" = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) Then
        If IsNumeric(objFSO.GetBaseName(objFile.Name)) Then
            objFSO.Movefile Drivespec,"D:\Deletable\"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

For some reason though I'm receiving an error on line 9 about files not being found. I'd added a msgbox(objFile) and I know that much works well enough, but what am I missing here?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm receiving an error stating that the file can't be found in line 9. I know it's finding files but I can't get them to be moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objFSO.Movefile Drivespec,"D:\Deletable\"`

Change `Drivespec` to `objFile.Path`